# How do I get the brightness keys working on a Samsung NC110?

Tags: brightness, 13.04, samsung

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on my Samsung NC110 notebook and the keys for the brightness aren't working. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me,

open a terminal.

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bkup 
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add the following to the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=".... acpiosi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor "

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

hope this helps :-)